# Cross platform way to get a list of availble fonts

Tags: fonts, cairo, pango

I'm using Pango and Cairo. Is there a simple way to get a list of available fonts? I'm willing to use another library, provided the solution is fairly simple.

Answer (score 1):

Pango has a set of font functions, to get a list of fonts, I needed to get **pango_font_map_list_families** then use **pango_font_family_list_faces** to get individual face information, although that is more than I need in this case.

Comment: I am working within a AWS chef installed environment. pango doesn't seem to have an pip installable package. is there one I am not finding?